# how to read perticular values in text files which contain different delimiters between text

Tags: c++

```
CamLeft_005936340000.tiff
1
1]X:56,Y:103,width:248,length:562
CamLeft_005936440000.tiff
1
1]X:50,Y:115,width:237,length:561
CamLeft_005936540000.tiff
1
1]X:49,Y:107,width:243,length:557
CamLeft_005936640000.tiff
```

this is the example of the text data in my text file . i have to read the values of x,y,width and length from the lines . please suggest me how can i read it in c++

Comment: The delimiters are constant for every third line, ignore the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read a line, verify if it matches the pattern `^[0..9]\]` and, if so, read the rest of the line as a CSV or parse the data you need (with sscanf maybe?)

Comment: can you please give me example code to just know it better , as i am new to c++ coding

Comment: I will leave that as an exercise for you - one of the best ways to learn a language is to read files and manipulate the input.  Search for file IO and regular expressions (regex).